# How to test change unit in mongock with its multiple attributes/lifecycle methods?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongock, mongobee

We recently migrated from MongoBee to Mongock, and with Mongock 5 version the `@ChangeLog` and `@ChangeSet` are depricated. Writing the `@ChangeUnit` is easy enough and rollback methods are very helpful.

However, I'm unable to figure out how to write a test simulating the migration in test DB and validating the changes in DB, as there are `@BeforeExecution`, `@RollbackBeforeExecution`, `@Execution` and `@RollbackExecution` attributes or lifecycle methods in a @ChangeUnit.

Earlier, I used to just call the method with `@ChangeSet` annotation like

```
assertOriginalStructure();
someMigrationChangeLog.updateIndexOnSomething();
assertIndexUpdated();
```

Now, I'm unsure if there is a clean way to write the above test as there is some logic in `@BeforeExecution` and also in `@Execution`. I know individually calling the annotated methods will work, but I wanted to know if there is a way to just run one `@ChangeUnit` as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version 5, the basic change is that a ChangeUnit holds the unit of execution. That's normally done in the method annotated with `@Execution`, so the first approach is just doing the same you are doing but calling the `@Execution` method:

```java
assertOriginalStructure();
someMigrationChangeUnit.updateIndexOnSomething();//annotated with @Execution
assertIndexUpdated();
```

However, your ChangeUnit can also provide`@BeforeExecution`, which would be used to perform any action that cannot be within the execution, for example, in a transactional MongoDB migration, DDL are not allowed inside a transaction, so that would be done in the `@BeforeExecution`. So if your changeUnit has both, `@Execution` and `@BeforeExecution`, you should do this:

```java
assertOriginalStructure();
someMigrationChangeUnit.beforeExecution();//annotated with @BeforeExecution
someMigrationChangeUnit.updateIndexOnSomething();//annotated with @Execution
assertIndexUpdated();
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand I can call both the methods individually, the reason I asked this question was in case there was a scenario where I also wanted to test the roll back works automatically. I again understand we can call the roll back in a catch block with execution in try. But wanted to see if there was a better option, looks like there isn't one for now. Thanks for quick reply tho.

Comment: That totally makes sense. But in case of a failure, in a transactional environment the rollback won't be executed and the execution is like it never took place. However,  the `@RollbackBeforeExecution` method is executed, as the `@BeforeExecution` is executed outside the transaction.

Comment: Notice we are working in providing some test utilities as you are not the first one asking about testing ;)